# Questions with audio from third-party sites

Tags: discussion

I've posted a couple of questions with embedded audio.

- [Miking a djembe](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/miking-a-djembe)
- [Recording in free time in a song with a click track](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/recording-in-free-time-in-a-song-with-a-click-track)

I'm sure that, eventually, I'll need to reclaim space in my Soundcloud account, and these links will break. Is there any way to upload audio to the site, similar to how the site now uses imgur for graphics? If not, what happens to these questions? (These two aren't so dependent on the audio that it's a big problem, but I'm sure there are questions here where it would be more of an issue.)

Similar issues exist for questions with embedded videos and audio from other sites.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to upload directly to Stack Exchange.

Conceivably, you could make a new Soundcloud account, just for hosting audio for your SE questions.